# Passing multidimensional array to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

Trying to pass multidimensional php array to Javascript using JSON. The code refuses to enter the success state of JSON, why is this?

This is javascript file:

```
array = [];

function callback(arr)
{
 console.log(array);
 //simpleText.setText = array[0]
};
$(document).ready(function() {
 $.getJSON('database.php', function(phpdata){
    console.log("po");
    console.log(phpdata);
    callback(phpdata);
  });

});
```

And php file:

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("atlas") or die(mysql_error()); 

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions") 
or die(mysql_error()); 

$i = 0;
$result_array = array();
 while ($Row = mysql_fetch_array($data)) 
{ 
$user[] = array( 
'id'=>$Row['id'], 
'q'=>$Row['q'],
'a'=>$Row['a'],
'coordx'=>$Row['coordx'],
'coordy'=>$Row['coordy'],
    ); 
} 


var_dump($user);

$json = json_encode($user[0]);


echo $json;
```

Comment: Share your JSON with us

Comment: You're not passing a multidimensional array. You're just passing `$user[0]`, which is one row, which is a one-dimensional array.

Comment: You need to take `var_dump()` out of the script. It will be read by `$.getJSON`, but it's not valid JSON.

Comment: As a total side-note, you should use `mysql_fetch_assoc` and then `$user[] = $Row;`, save yourself some time and energy by letting the mysql driver do the work for you (http://us2.php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the

```
var_dump($user);
```

line. It's making the result invalid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

`getJSON` jQuery function does not return errors. Use `ajax` function below and check your error message and returned JSON (inside `jqXHR` object):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'database.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        // success
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // error
    }
});
```

Comment: It seems like i'm getting a SyntaxError{} from the errorThrown, any idea why?